# Bias of Instrumental Variables Estimator

Tags: regression, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, instrumental-variables

Given the IV estimator for $\beta_1$ (From $y = \beta_0 +\beta_1x + u$):

$$\beta_1 = \frac{Cov(z, y)}{Cov(z, x)}$$

And it's sample analog:

$$\hat{\beta_1} = \frac{\hat{Cov}(z, y)}{\hat{Cov}(z, x)}$$

Which simplifies to:

$$\hat{\beta_1} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(z_i-\bar{z})(\beta_0 +\beta_1x_i + u)}{\sum_{i=1}^n(z_i - \bar{z})(x_i - \bar{x})} \rightarrow \beta_1 + \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(z_i - \bar{z})u_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n(z_i - \bar{z})(x_i - \bar{x})} $$

Surely this estimator is unbiased because $Cov(z, u)=0$ by the assumption of exogeneity when dealing with instruments? Even if the above represents the sample covariance, because the sample covariance is an unbiased estimator of the population covariance, then surely $\hat{\beta_1}$ is still unbiased?

Aside from that, why is it necessary to take the conditional expectation on *both* $X$ and $Z$?.

$$E[\hat{\beta_1}] = E[E[\hat{\beta_1}|X, Z]] \rightarrow \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(z_i - \bar{z})E[u_i|X, Z]}{\sum_{i=1}^n(z_i - \bar{z})(x_i - \bar{x})}$$

I can see why this expression isn't equal to zero (Because of the implication of the conditional on $X$), but why do we have to take that expectation instead of simply $E[\hat{\beta_1}] = E[E[\hat{\beta_1}|X]] $ or $E[E[\hat{\beta_1}|Z]]$? Is it necessary to condition on all of the data within the model?

Answer (score 0):

The IV estimator you mention is a special case of [two-stage least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumental_variables_estimation#Interpretation_as_two-stage_least_squares) (TSLS) for a single endogenous variable ($x$). TSLS is *asymptotically* unbiased. It has a bias of order $\mathcal{O}(\frac{1}{n})$ (c.f. Fuller, 1977, Theorem 1 for $\alpha=0$). Fuller (1977) proposed an adjustment of the TSLS that has a bias of order $\mathcal{O}(\frac{1}{n^2})$ (c.f. Fuller, 1977, Theorem 1 for $\alpha=1$). Note that when people refer to the Fuller(1) estimator, they typically refer to an adjustment to the [limited information maximum likelihood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_equations_model#Limited_information_maximum_likelihood_(LIML)) (LIML), which is the MLE of the causal parameter assuming Gaussian perturbations.

Fuller, Wayne (1977). "Some Properties of a Modification of the Limited Information Estimator". Econometrica. 45 (4): 939–953. doi:10.2307/1912683. JSTOR 1912683.